# Don't turn/switch the light on and off

Tags: grammar

He switched the light on and off rapidly.

**"Don't turn/switch the light on and off."**

Does it sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: Is he doing this action repeatedly?

Comment: Both sound natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural to say "Don't switch the light off" or "Don't turn the light off".  However in the situation you describe your child (I assume) is turning the light rapidly on and off, which is annoying.  In this case you would tell him.

> Don't **play with** the light switch!

"Play with" has a number of meanings, one of which is to use something *playfully*, and not in the manner it's meant to be used:

> Don't **play with** the radio settings in the car.  You'll **mess them up**.
>
> Don't **play with** that blender.  **It's not a toy**.

Of course this doesn't have to be negative.

> It's really hot today, why don't you go **play with** the hose in the backyard?  That will cool you off.

(By this I mean that he should use the hose to spray himself with water.)

Answer (score 1):

Use *turn*, not *switch*.

Although *switch* can be used as a verb, in most day-to-day conversations, we **turn** lights on and off. At least in most US dialects I know, the normal verb is *turn,* and the normal noun is *switch*.

For example:

> Where is the light switch? I can't find the switch.
>
> Don't turn the lights off and on like that!

Again, there is nothing grammatically wrong with "Don't switch the lights off and on like that," but I don't think that's the most natural way to say it.